# Error activating the Molecular addon in Blender 3.0

Tags: modeling, objects, particles, add-on, physics

I just started doing the particle exercises and for that, I need to use the **Molecular addon**. I use Blender 3.0. I downloaded the addon and installed it. The problem appears when I want it to activate in the preferences and I get an error message.

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. English is mandatory language for the site. If you are not comfortable writing in English feel free to use any online translation service.

Comment: first make sure you use the latest release. otherwise check with the addon's author on their github: https://github.com/scorpion81/Blender-Molecular-Script/releases